# Clearing the Filter Sorting of Telerik RadGrid on PostBack

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

How can we remove the Sorting of data previously done on a Telerik RadGrid on Post Back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the SortExpression of Master Table view to clear.
Example:

```
_rdGrdReport.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
```

if grid name is _rdGrdReport

Comment: Again you have reply in flash and it is the exact thing i wanted. Thanks a lot. :)